# Як перекласти слово badge?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Як правильно перекласти на українську слово бейдж (табличка, яку вішають на шию, чи пристібають до одягу, з даними про людину, яка цю табличку носить)? [Google-перекладач](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#en/uk/badge) пропонує такі варіанти: значок, бляха, емблема, знак розрізнення, ознака, символ. З цього усього мабуть значок підходить найбільше, але це не зовсім те:

> ЗНАЧО́К, чка, чол.
>   1. Невеличка, перев. металева пластинка прямокутної, округлої і т. ін. форми з певними зображеннями, якою нагороджують кого-небудь за заслуги або яку носять на знак солідарності з ким-, чим-небудь, приналежності до якоїсь організації чи на згадку про визначну подію. Блиснув на школярському козирку бурсацький значок (Степан Васильченко, I, 1959, 188); Хома розстебнувся, виставляючи груди з гвардійським значком і медаллю «За відвагу» (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 251); Ось чималий значок — у червоному емалевому колі біжить спортсмен, грудьми розриваючи золоту фінішну стрічку (Вадим Собко, Стадіон, 1954, 67).

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/beidzh) також знайшла такі варіанти: найменка, нагрудний ідентифікатор. Особисто мені, найбільш правильним здається ідентифікатор, чи нагрудний ідентифікатор. Але воно не зареєстроване словниками. То як правильно перекласти слово badge(бейдж)?

Comment: Для худоби така штука називається **[би́рка](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3871)** («невеличка дощечка або металева бляшка з номером або написом, яку прив'язують до шиї тваринам»). Але людям, що носитимуть це, така асоціація навряд сподобається. Хоча, по-моєму, таке поширення було б логічним, адже сучасне значення слова _бирка_ вийшло далеко за межі дощечки на шию худобі, а поширюєтсья зокрема на будь-якого матеріалу мітки, но чіпляють в будь-якому місці до будь-яких предметів (навіть до неістот).

Comment: Це залежить від змісту. В словнику https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/badge можна зрозуміти, що залежно від змісту можна підібрати декілька слів. Але я б вказав загальне слово як підпис. Можете навести приклад речення, де ви хочете вказати слово badge?

Answer (score 1):

Згідно до сайту [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/beidzh), який Ви також навели у питанні, то найкращий варіант буде "найменик", і я з цим погоджуюся, адже це слово утворне від українського слова ["наймення"](http://sum.in.ua/s/najmennja), а от "ідентифікатор" походить від англійського "to identify", тобто якщо Ви шукаєте саме український відповідник, то воно Вам не підійде.

Answer (score 0):

[**Name tag**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_tag) **(Badge)** **[** **[бірка з іменем](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0b/Caitlin%27s_name_badge_%282722635443%29.jpg)**, **[іменна табличка](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Lanyard_mit_Logo_bedruckt.jpg)**, **[бейдж](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lieutenant_General_Valerii_Zaluzhnyi.jpg#/media/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Lieutenant_General_Valerii_Zaluzhnyi.jpg)** **]** – це [значок](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BA) або [наліпка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0), яку носять на верхньому одязі як засіб відображення імені власника для перегляду іншими.

---

[Digital Badge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badge) - значок, наліпка, відзнака, [бейдж](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B6).